# Debugging component from npm

Tags: reactjs

So i've downloaded component from npm called AwesomeButton and i want to debug this component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AwesomeButtonProgress } from "react-awesome-button";
import "react-awesome-button/dist/styles.css";
```

tried to open index.d.ts file which `react-awesome-button` referencing, but the code is just like this without class which contain all func

```
declare module 'react-awesome-button' {
  import React, { Component } from 'react';

  export interface AwesomeButtonProps {
    action?(): void;
    active: boolean;
    blocked: boolean;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    className: string;
    cssModule: object;
    disabled: boolean;
    element?(): void;
    href: string;
    moveEvents: boolean;
    onPress?(): void;
    onReleased?(): void;
    placeholder: boolean;
    ripple: boolean;
    rootElement: string;
    size: string;
    style: object;
    target: string;
    title: string;
    to: string;
    type: string;
    visible: boolean;
  }

  export default class AwesomeButton extends Component<
    AwesomeButtonProps,
    {}
  > {}

  export interface AwesomeButtonProgressProps {
    action?(): void;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    cssModule: object;
    disabled: boolean;
    fakePress: boolean;
    loadingLabel: string;
    onPress?(): void;
    releaseDelay: number;
    resultLabel: string;
    rootElement: React.ReactNode;
    size: string;
    type: string;
  }

  export default class AwesomeButtonProgress extends Component<
    AwesomeButtonProgressProps,
    {}
  > {}

  export interface AwesomeButtonSocialProps {
    action?(): void;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    disabled: boolean;
    href: string;
    icon: boolean;
    iconHeight: number;
    iconWidth: number;
    image: string;
    message: string;
    onPress?(): void;
    phone: string;
    type: string;
    url: string;
    user: string;
  }

  export default class AwesomeButtonSocial extends Component<
    AwesomeButtonSocialProps,
    {}
  > {}
}
```

i want to know where is the component class so i can debug that code

Answer (score 0):

The code for the modules are all located on node_modules folder. If you want to go straight to that classe's code, you simply hold Control and click on the class name.

The file index.d.ts is just the 'typing' file used by Typescript